# Difference on arrays, lists, hashes

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, difference

Is there a concept and/or algorithms that deal with the minimal sequence of elementary operations to handle differences between structured objects such as arrays/lists/hashes? I am imagining something like various notions of string distances, but I want to handle not only strings. For example, the difference between the first and the second arrays below:

```
["a", {b: 1}, false, "b"]
[{b: 1}, "a", false, true]
```

can be represented by two operations: transposing elements at indices `0` and `1` and replacing the element at index `3` with `true`. Replacing the whole array may apparently seem less (single) operation, but that involves larger objects, and should not be counted as the minimal operation. Is there a notion like this in programming?

I don't know what exactly should be considered as elementary operations that would make sense. I imagine insertion, deletion, (and perhaps transposition, substitution and/or assignment of a value under a different key in case of a hash). They should all be dealing with the structural difference. I clearly don't want to include operations like "add +3 to a number."

Comment: My first-impression reaction is that this is a masquerade for *The Halting Problem.*

Comment: It all depends on what operations are elementary.

Comment: @VaughnCato That is part of the question.

Comment: This can be solved with dynamic programming as long as the state diagram forms a k-tree with a small treewidth.

Comment: Based on your example, your problem is still basically an edit-distance problem, your alphabet is just contains structured items as well a primitive items.  If you want to include the cost of editing the structured items as well, this can be done by recursively considering the weight for a pair of structured items to be the edit distance for those structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you can encode the data structure as a string then you could use a variant of something like the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm.  Assign a different symbol to each unique element of the two data structures, in this case "a" = A, {b: 1} = B, false = C, true = D, and "b" = E; then you'd be looking for the edit distance between the strings ABCE and BACD

Comment: That will not work (at least trivially) because Levenshtein distance only considers operations on characters, not sequences of characters.

Comment: @sawa The only solution that comes to mind is to re-run the algorithm using different permutations of string encodings, for example one permutation would use the symbol A for "a" and B for {b: 1}, while another uses the symbol A' for the sequence ["a", {b: 1}].  Unfortunately this runs you into a combinatorial explosion

Comment: @sawa A more efficient solution is to store a list of the start and final indices of all transpositions; when the base algorithm terminates, sort this list by starting indices, and if any two or more starting indices are adjacent and also have adjacent final indices then reduce the transposition count by [the number of adjacent characters - 1] (since you'll have transposed the two or more adjacent characters in one operation)